# Query between two tables in the same data set in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to make a query between two tables. The first table is the one that reposites all the information of the firebase events and I focus on a field and it is the userid, this parameter is being sent encrypted from the setting of the events at the request of the client. What I do is to collect each encrypted userid, decrypt it and create a table with the encrypted and decrypted userid. When I make the query, making the match between the encrypted fields of the two tables does not bring me any information but there is, there is a warning that no results were obtained for the query. I will exemplify how I am doing the query.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  DISTINCT user_id AS registered_user,
  userid,
  userdescifrado
FROM
  `mi-firebase-app.analytics_152734570.events_20191118` a,
  `mi-firebase-app.analytics_152734570.user_id` b
WHERE 
  event_name = 'first_open'
AND 
  user_id != 'null'
AND
  a.user_id = b.userid
LIMIT 100
```

[Firebase table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWaXg.png)

[Created table structure where decrypted userid are hosted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFs8l.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recommend you to perform a simple query by removing additional conditions to validate if there are encrypted user IDs that match in both tables.

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT 
  DISTINCT user_id AS registered_user, userid, userdescifrado 
FROM 
  `mi-firebase-app.analytics_152734570.events_20191118` a, 
  `mi-firebase-app.analytics_152734570.user_id` b 
WHERE  
  a.user_id = b.userid 
LIMIT 100
```

If by running the aforementioned query you still not receiving results, it could be related to whitespaces at the beginning or/and the end of each user id string, so you could try to use the [“TRIM” function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#trim) to remove them, please see the following example:

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT 
  DISTINCT user_id AS registered_user, userid, userdescifrado 
FROM 
  `mi-firebase-app.analytics_152734570.events_20191118` a, 
  `mi-firebase-app.analytics_152734570.user_id` b 
WHERE  
  trim(a.user_id) = trim(b.userid) 
LIMIT 100
```

Once you get results; you can add your additional conditions. If you continue not receiving results with the last test, there may not be any match between the IDs of both tables.

Comment: Hi Noe,

Thank you for taking your time and answering my questions. I have applied your solution and it has helped me. Thank you very much, successes!

Answer (score 0):

Here I was trying a similar query in order to see how this works, the query is in `stackoverflow` free dataset data from Bigquery

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT a.user_id AS user_id_a,
  b.user_id as b,
  text
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.badges` a,
  `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.comments` b
WHERE 
  name = 'Teacher'
AND 
  a.user_id IS NOT NULL
AND
  a.user_id = b.user_id
LIMIT 100
```

And this gives some results.
The difference with your query is the `IS NOT NULL` check. In my case `user_id` column is `INTEGER`

Could be that in that partition you have selected there is no data for your query?
Maybe use a larger time interval there.

[Results of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlBA3.png)

Comment: Hi Alina,

Thank you very much for taking the time to try and answer my question.

I have adapted my query very similar to the one you answered

I executed the query and it still comes out "No results were obtained for the query."

I don't know if it's because of the length of the encryption that it can break the query and don't bring data.

In my case, the
two data with which I try to match (userid and user_id) are of type String